# Using reverse proxy in apache 2, php environment where server ip is known at run time and can not be visible in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2, reverse-proxy

I have to configure reverse proxy on the server so that user could not be able to see the actual server ip which is about to connect. He must be able to see only {base address}/configure as

> rocking.com/configure

. I did try this via .htaccess with the below rewrite rule ->

```
RewriteRule ^configure http://$1 [P]
```

But the problem is, I can not make visible the connecting server Ip in the Url in query parameters as {base address}/configure?machineIP=192.168.0.190 and without this I can not write the above RewriteRule. Adding to this, connecting IP gets known at run time.
What options do I have left?

Comment: RewriteRules are not for proxying requests. Have a look at mod_proxy in apache: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html

Comment: May be u r right !! But I just came to know via->http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#forwardreverse